# Bash pattern matching: exclude a given string

Tags: bash, file, pattern-matching

The current folder contains subfolders, each of which contains among others a file I want to process.

Files I'm interested in look like:

```
someSubFolderCommonPathName*/*commonStringInFileName*
```

My problem is that I also have files I **don't** want to process whose name is the same as above and which end with `_stringNotToMatch`:

```
someSubFolderCommonPathName*/*commonStringInFileName*_stringNotToMatch
```

How do I **exclude** them in my pattern matching expression?

A simple example could be:

```
for i in someSubFolderCommonPathName*/*commonStringInFileName*!(stringNotToMatch); do stat $i; done
```

... but it doesn't work.

Ok, if I furtherly simplify this, here is an example:
I have the following:

```
me@my-laptop:~/a$ ls -R
.:
aPrettyBoy  aPrettyGirl

./aPrettyBoy:
12cool21  12nice21  77nice77_ugly

./aPrettyGirl:
12cool21  12nice21  23nice23_ugly
```

And then I try to do show all files containing `nice` in their names and not `_ugly`:

```
me@my-laptop:~/a$ for i in *Pretty*/*nice*!(_ugly); do echo $i; done
aPrettyBoy/12nice21
aPrettyBoy/77nice77_ugly
aPrettyGirl/12nice21
aPrettyGirl/23nice23_ugly
```

It didn't work. I'll include a star now:

```
me@my-laptop:~/a$ for i in *Pretty*/*nice*!(*_ugly); do echo $i; done
aPrettyBoy/12nice21
aPrettyBoy/77nice77_ugly
aPrettyGirl/12nice21
aPrettyGirl/23nice23_ugly
```

Still not working.
NOw with `find`:

```
me@my-laptop:~/a$ find . -path "*Pretty*/*nice*" ! -name "_ugly" -exec echo {} \;
./aPrettyBoy/12nice21
./aPrettyBoy/77nice77_ugly
./aPrettyGirl/23nice23_ugly
./aPrettyGirl/12nice21
```

Nada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The negative extended glob pattern is a bit problematic. Let's simplify the situation a bit: we want `*nice*`, but we do not want `ugly` at the end. If we enter

```
*nice*!(ugly)
```

then everything containing `nice` will match: the asterisk before the negative pattern eats the `u` as well, and the `gly` at the end is not ugly anymore. Moreover, the strings ending in `nice` will not be matched.

To workaround, move the asterisk into the negative pattern:

```
*nice!(*ugly)
```

Comment: In my case, the part before and after `nice` always varies. The only constants are `nice` somewhere in the middle and `_ugly` at the end. I tried with and without `*` inside the brackets, but I'm still getting those unwanted files...

Comment: OK, I added an example based on your answer.

Comment: @RickyRobinson: You added an asterisk, while you should have *moved* it.

Answer (score 1):

Using `find`:

```
find . -path "./someSubFolderCommonPathName*/*commonStringInFileName*" ! -name "*_stringNotToMatch" -exec stat {} \;
```

Comment: It works for me. Did you run exactly the same command in the directory containing `someSubFolderCommonPathName`?

Comment: I added an example with also your solution. COuld you please give it a look? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You forgot the wildcard. Use `-name "*_ugly"` in your `find` command, like in my answer.